# Regular Expression for Email Validation

Tags: regex, validation, email

I have an issue trying to get a correct regex for an email validator for my jQuery validate plugin.  I'm trying to get an expression that will only allow email addresses like the following:

firstname.mi.lastname.civ (or .mil)

Lastname should allow a number.  And addresses should only be allowed from a select set of domains:  (ndu.edu or nps.edu or any address from .mil or .gov)

I've been playing around with RegExr.com, which is great, but I'm having a problem getting the right combo to work in all my situations.  Here is what I have so far:

^[A-Z0-9]+.([A-Z0-9]+.)*([A-Z0-9]+)+@([-a-z0-9_]+(.[-a-z0-9_]+)*((nps.edu|ndu.edu)|.(gov|mil)))(:[0-9])?$

This works okay for:
firstname.mi.lastname@mail.mil  (or .gov)
and for
firstname.mi.lastname1@mail.mil (or .gov)

But I can get my other domains to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am getting rather frustrated trying to get this completed.  I admit I'm not that savvy with regex!

Comment: Update:  I changed my original to this:   ^[-a-z0-9]+\.([-a-z0-9]+\.)*([-a-z0-9]+)*(.civ|.mil)+(@ndu.edu|@nps.edu|@(.*?).(gov|mil))(:[0-9])?$  Now it will accept an address like:  firstname.mi.lastname.civ (or .mil), but now it won't accept just firstname.mi.lastname@mail.mil (or .gov)  Additionally, I now see a problem where it will accept @mail..mil.  Ugh!!  I need help!

Comment: I apologize for the way this comment looks.  I can't seem to get the line breaks to work.

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with the unescaped `.`.

Comment: try something like `[a-z]+\.[a-z]\.[a-z]+\d{0,}@(ndu\.edu|nps\.edu|.+\.(?:mil|gov))`

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me.  Here is what I ended up doing just to get past this...  ^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@(nps.edu|ndu.edu|[a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*(\.gov|\.mil))$   This works for all cases for me.